# How create model class in PHP?

Tags: php

I have income request as POST data. It looks as `Request $request`.

I can retrieve data: `$request->name`

I want to create model class based on this data, using set/get.

How to do that in PHP?

I tried:

```
class UserModel {

    private $name;

   public __constructor(Request $request) {
     $this->name = $request->name; 
  }
}
```

How to use get/set?

Can I create interface and use object like:

```
   interface IUser {
       name: string;
    }

$obj = $request as IUser;
```

Comment: I suggest you have a read through [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Does PHP give an error? Do you have namespaces? You could escape Namespaces with ```\Request```

Comment: I need Overloading in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserModel.php :

```
class UserModel {
    public $name;
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->name = $request->name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Request.php

```
class Request
{
    public $name;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = "John";
    }
}
```

Main.php

```
require_once("UserModel.php");
require_once("Request.php");
$request = new Request();
$myClass = new UserModel($request);
//Using get
echo $myClass->getName();
//Using set
$myClass->setName("Jill");
echo "\n";
echo $myClass->getName();
echo "\n";
```

Usage of get and set is displayed in Main.php.

Request.php is a mock to replace the class Request you are using.

The code is available at https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/https-stackoverflow.com-questions-57240050. Run it with `php7.2 Main.php` .

This example sets the visibilty of all attributes and methods to public. Be aware of that.

Comment: Why not to use get/set?

Comment: You mean __get and __set from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get ?